# Login system, logs you out every time you reload

Tags: php, mysql, session, authentication

I've been bothered by this problem for quite a while now, and i just can't figure it out. Once a user tries to login, he's being logged in. But once he loads another page, or refreshes he's logged out right away. The really weird thing is, that once i test it locally on XAMPP it works without a problem, but when it runs on my webpage, it dosen't work. They run on almost the same version of PHP 5.5.11 (locally) 5.5.18 (on webpage) Can anyone explain me what's wrong? Any help is greatly appreciated

From login.php

```
      $query = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE email='$email' AND password='$passi' AND com_code IS NULL";
      $result = mysqli_query($mysqli,$query)or die(mysqli_error());
      $num_row = mysqli_num_rows($result);
      $row=mysqli_fetch_array($result);
      if( $num_row ==1 )
      {
       $_SESSION['user_name']=$row['username'];

        header("Location: index.php");


  }


  else
         {

   $message= "Wrong login message";
  }
```

From my other pages, that checks if the user is logged in:

```
 if($_SESSION['user_name'] == '') {
   die ("Please log in to see this page");

    } else {

        echo "Hey $_SESSION[user_name]!";
    }
```

Comment: You never start your session with `session_start();`

Comment: Do you have session_start() at the top of each PHP page?

Comment: I just solved the problem. I had the session_start(); in the somewhat top, but not completely. I fixed it by, simply placing session_start(); in the absoloute top. Thank you :)

Comment: [Prevent SQL Injection!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: Hello jay, i already did infact, i just didn't show you. You can see it here:    http://pastebin.com/NpZUnsdz Will this prevent that kind of SQL injections?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i fixed the problem.
I a session_start(); in the somewhat top of the page, but not completely. I fixed it by, simply placing session_start(); in the absoloute top. Thank you :)